# Spring prototype bean confiusion

Tags: java, spring, prototype

Consider the following classes:

```
@Component
@Scope(scopeName = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class PrototypeBean
{
    public void method1() { ... };
    public void method2() { ... };
}

@Component
public class SingletonBean
{
   @Autowired
   private PrototypeBean prototypeBean;

   public void SingletonBean doSomething()
   {
      prototypeBean.method1();
      prototypeBean.method2();

   }
}
```

Now, I would expect that everytime doSomething() method is called, a new PrototypeBean instance is created and injected to SingletonBean.
But what really happens is a new PrototypeBean instance is created and injected into SingletonBean when I call method1() and method2().

I don't really get why, this should've worked as far is I'm concerned.
Please correct my if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, That is expected !!

Because you declared the bean's scope attribute as `prototype` `@Scope(scopeName = "prototype")`that force the Spring IoC container creates a new bean instance of the object every time a request for that specific bean is made.

Note:As a rule, use the prototype scope for all state-full beans and the singleton scope for stateless beans.

Comment: Oh, ok. I was almost convinced that a new instance will bean created each time doSomething method is called. Well then, it seems like I have to find a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is expected since beans are only initialized on demand, for prototype scope the bean will be initialized each time it is needed.